# Jquery UI Dialog - Passing Dynamic Variable and changing dialog form html

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a upload document dialog created with jqueryUI that works great, but I need to add it to a page with multiple tabs, and rotate the default document type in the drop down box as well as change a hidden value in the form that is used by the form validation (primarily to return to the correct tab after upload).

I could just create a dozen of these slightly re-named at the bottom of the page so that each dialog is unique, from each unique button click, but that creates a lot of unnecessary bloat on a page that is already probably too large.

What I really want is to pass a number in the source click that automatically changes the hidden input field and changes the default dropbox selection (they are directly related)

Unfortunately my coding skills are still noobish, I am pretty good with php but javascript and ajax are still kinda new to me.  This is an internal office document sharing system between remote offices, I only get to code part time so unfortunately I get a bit rusty... :)

```
<div id="upload" title="Upload Documents" style="margin: 0 0 0 0" ><div id="upload-Wrapper"><p >To add documents, please select your document on your computer and enter a description and classification.&nbsp;Maximum file size is 25 megabytes per document uploaded.</p>

<form action="updoc.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<div class="auto-style2">
<br/><label>Select Document</label><input type="file" name="pdfdoc" value="" style="width: 279px" />
<br/>   <br/>
<label style="width: 113px">Document Type</label>
<select name="doc_type" id="doc_type" style="width: 281px">
<option value="T">RT</option> <!--This is the default value for the first tab, but on others I need to rotate the list so the correct one is default-->
<option value="C">CT</option>
<option value="A">TA</option>
<option value="P">PA</option>
<option value="D">AD</option>
<option value="H">DH</option>
<option value="L">LW</option>
<option value="V">LWD</option>
<option value="W">LWT</option>
<option value="R">PR</option>
<option value="O">Other</option>
</select>
<br/>   <br/>
<label style="width: 140px">Description </label>
<input type="text" name="pdfdesc" value="" style="width: 309px" />
<br/>
<p>*all fields required  
<input type='hidden' value='3' name='tab' /> <!--This is the hidden value I need to change depending on the source click-->
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File" style="float:none; margin-left: 85px"  /></p>
</div>
</form>
</div><!--end Contact-Wrapper-->
</div>

<script>
var dialogOpts = {
bgiframe: true,
autoOpen: false,
modal: true,
width: "521px"
};

$('#upload').dialog(dialogOpts);
$('#upload-Links').click(function() {
  $('#upload').dialog('open');
  return false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. What do you mean by the "source click"?

Out of what I understood, here's what I came up with. The following script will change the dropdown to `CT` when a `.txt` file is selected, and to `TA` when a `.png` file is selected.

No matter what file is selected the filename will be put into the hidden field.

```
$('input[name=pdfdoc]').change(function() {
    var f = $(this).val(); // file name
    var dt = $('#doc_type'); // drop down
    switch (f.split('.').pop()) { // check the file extension
        case 'txt':
            dt.val('C');
            break;
        case 'png':
            dt.val('A');
            break;
    }
    $('input[name=tab]').val(f); // store the file name in the hidden field
});
```

Let me know if this is not exactly what you were looking for - I'll update the answer.